# How to properly shut down a tcp socket connection in spring?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `Spring integration` to manage a socket connection on the server side.
How can I ensure that any active socket connections are terminated properly if the server (tomcat) is shutdown?

```
<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="server"
    connection-factory="fac"
    request-channel="chan"
    error-channel="errorChan" />
```

Is there some kind listener? Or any interceptor that can prevent server shutdown, e.g. for max 60 seconds if there is any open socket during shutdown; but meanwhile close the socket to not accept any connections during shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a Listener and shutting down the socket gate with a specific timeout in case there are any inflight messages (`actives` see below).

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private TcpInboundGateway gate;

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationMBeanExporter bean;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent e) {
        //return
        int actives = gate.beforeShutdown();

            if (actives == 0) {
                bean.stopActiveComponents(true, 0);
            } else {
                bean.stopActiveComponents(false, timeout);
            }
    }
}
```